# Determine the value of M and does M depends on k?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

Here is an exercise I'm struggling with:

> One way to improve the performance of QuickSort is to switch to
>   InsertionSort when a subfile has <= M elements instead of recursively calling itself.
>
> Implement a recursive QuickSort with a cutoff to InsertionSort for subfiles with M or less elements. Empirically determine the value of M for which it performs fewest key comparisons on inputs of 60000 random natural numbers less than K for K = 10,100,1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000. Does the optimal value M depend on K?

My issues:
I would like to know whether the value of M differs from statement 1 and statement 3. If so, what would be the array size, and how to vary the random numbers ? How to compare M and K? Do i have any mathematical equation or i should it just do it using my code ?

Comment: `Empirically determine` sounds to me like you're supposed to try it out and see.

Answer (score 2):

1. Implement the sort algoritm as requested.
2. Add support for recording the number of comparisons (e.g. increment a global)
3. Generate 5 sets of input data for each k. So 30 files with 1,800,000 lines in total.
4. Run the sort on every set for every K and guess M a couple of times. Start with the low-valued inputs and make the favorable M guide your guesses as you progress towards high-valued inputs.
5. Describe your observations about the influence of M over K.
6. Pass the exercise like a pro